# How to customize date selection in R shiny using dataframe values

Tags: r, date, shiny

I have a dataframe with date in one column and other variables related, for the same dates, I have raster and vector information that I want to display. I am building a dashboard in shiny and I would like to customized the selection based on dates where data is available. As you can see I am using min and max dates but not steps. I have read this other post [link to stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175398/interactive-and-dynamic-map-with-wind-data-in-r-leaflet) in which they use steps to define the days in between but in my case I do not have data every 5 days for example. So I would like to use the dates in the dataframe as steps. Is it possible? Besides that, I do not know why my dates in tables are being presented as numbers. Any tips to present them with proper format?

For the reprex below I am not including the raster nor vector data, but the same principle appies. The way I am filtering raster data is by using a name with date information like id_date.tif (ex.:"231_2020-01-23.tif")

```
#

library(shiny)

#dummy data for reprex

dd<-c("2020-01-02","2020-01-05","2020-01-12","2020-06-06")
yield<-c(12 , 13, 15, 22)
ph<-c(0.55,0.60,0.65,0.8)  
df<-data.frame(dd,yield,ph)
str(df)
df

df$dd<-as.Date(dd,"%Y-%m-%d",origin="1970-01-01")
str(df)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("custom slider with dates"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(


            sliderInput("date_s",
                        "Time of data collection: ",
                        min = min(df$dd),
                        max = max(df$dd),
                        value = min(df$dd),
                        #step = df$dd[1],
                        animate = TRUE)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            h3("Table 1. Date selection"),
            tableOutput("table1"),
            h3("Table 2. DF subset based on date selection"),
            tableOutput("table2"),
            h3("Table 3. Complete DF"),
            tableOutput("table3")

        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    #table 1 selection
    output$table1<-renderTable({
        ds<-format(as.Date(input$date_s,origin="1970-01-01"),"%Y-%m-%d")
        return(ds)
    })
    
    #table 2 subset
    output$table2<-renderTable({
        dfs<-df[df$dd == input$date_s,]
        return(dfs)
    })
    
    #table 3 all
    output$table3<-renderTable({
    
        return(df)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `?dateInput` ? It allows you to select dates from a calendar and disable specific dates or days of the week to the user as options.

Comment: Hi Baroque, thanks for your comment but dateInput is not what I am looking for. Probably what I need to do is develop a custom widget but I was wondering if somemone has done something similar. The dateInput allows you to select any date but you need to know for which date you have data available. As I have writen, data is not at regular intervals so could be any date so I was thinking to use a slider like widgets with points or steps at every date with available data of interest. Another interesting option could be to have some kind of mark for the dates of interest in calendar.

Comment: Hmm, did you check out the `datesdisabled` option of `dateInput`? You can make a sequence of dates like `sq <- seq(min(df$dd),max(df$dd))` and then do `sq <- !(sq %in% df$dd)` to get the dates not in the set. And then do `dateInput(....,datesdisabled=sq)` ? Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you Baroque for point up the datesdisable attribute. It helps, is not exactly the Calendar display what I wanted but it helps at this moment. I was looking for a timeline display type. Thanks!